# How do I integrate Microsoft Forms Pro with CRM? Is it possible to update an Account record based on a survey response?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-forms

I'd like to be able to send a Microsoft Forms Pro survey from an Account in CRM by changing an option set field from No to Yes.  The survey contains one text field. Once the survey has been completed, I want the survey response to be added to a text field in the Account form.  How can I do this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do so. This has been well documented and there are lot of ideas which are implemented and Proof of concept has been done.

There is an MVP Megan Walker on Forms PRO especially related to dynamics 365.
Here is an [link](https://meganvwalker.com/microsoft-forms-pro/) for her Blogs

There are no of blogs from here. Here is one specific [example](https://meganvwalker.com/send-forms-pro-survey-on-case-closure/) for crm

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Power Automate (formally Microsoft Flow) is your friend for this if you want to do it without any code. Otherwise you will need to develop a custom plugin to do this..

A good start would be this Flow, it fires a Forms Pro survey when a case is resolved (presuming you are running Dynamics in the CDS not on prem), you just need to change the trigger action. Then you'll probably need another flow to trigger on the survey being filled out and suck it back into Dynamics...

A good starting point for you first flow: 
https://emea.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/900eb2958a1648efb8f509da88242a8d/send-a-survey-when-a-case-is-resolved-in-dynamics-365/

Tons of templates in here: 
https://emea.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/